# typescript import external libraries

Tags: typescript, p5.js

I'm trying to use the `p5.js` library for typescript. I have installed it using `npm i @types/p5 p5`, and importing it in the code as:

```
import p5 from "p5";
```

seems to compile just fine. However, when I run the HTML of the project in the browser I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "p5". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

My `.ts` code is in a subfolder called `TS`, the compiled javascript is in a folder called `JS` and the module was installed in a third subfolder called `node_modules`.

This is how it looks from VSCode:

[image]

Also, this is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "ES2015",
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,    
    "moduleResolution": "Classic",
    "esModuleInterop": true,      
    "skipLibCheck": true,         
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to help me? Thanks!

Comment: I've found this example of usage that seems to be working fine... https://codesandbox.io/s/p5js-with-typescript-8rgs6 See if that fits your code.

Comment: It gives the same error...

Comment: @JacksonSilva the key problem I have is that it wants the import to have relative path, but the typescript compiler doesn't want to.

Comment: Try switching `moduleResolution` to `node`

Comment: For me, the codesandbox works. It imports `P5`. Furthermore, you need to change your TS Folder to `src` or change the `rootDir` in the `tsconfig.json` to `TS`. The one with `src` should be more preferable. When it still doesn't work, look further into the differences of the tsconfig.json as suggested in the comment from Chris Gilardi.

Comment: probably module resolution, set node

Comment: @b2f I did that already, but I didn't update the image in the question.